# FFmpeg recording works on one laptop but not the other

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, camera

The following command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" out.mp4​
```

works on one laptop (with C920 LogiTech camera) (Im calling it GOOD LAPTOP). It outputs a recorded video. But it will fail on another laptop (called BAD LAPTOP) and by fail on another I mean - it doesnt output a video (see below for output).

The suggestions are to change parameters based on the specific error that occur on BAD LAPTOP. I have tried many different suggestions but they dont seem to work. Furthermore, they dont provide much insight into the underlying cause of the problem.

Ive used the same camera on both laptops. Im using static windows binaries downloaded from FFmpeg web-site (veranoe). Please note the versions used below were different but that doesnt appear to matter.

Trying to diagnose. Anyone have an idea of where the problem may lie. It seems to indicate a problem at the level of the system / camera setup.

Please note that I've updated BAD LAPTOP but still no dice. Also please note that Ive tried this on several systems already and it seems to run ok (i.e., produce an output video)

BAD LAPTOP:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -f dshow -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -t 10 -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" out.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2019-11-26-59d264b Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191125
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavcodec     58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
  libavformat    58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
  libavfilter     7. 67.100 /  7. 67.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=HD Pro Webcam C920':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
video=HD Pro Webcam C920: I/O error
[libx264 @ 06cb7a00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 06cb7a00] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 06cb7a00] 264 - core 158 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 10000k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.62.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

GOOD LAPTOP:
​

```
$ ffmpeg -y -f dshow -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -t 10 -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920" out.mp4   
ffmpeg version N-92780-gbb586a9703 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers                              
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181201                                                                         
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ico
nv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --en
able-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-lib
soxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx
264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvi
dstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enabl
e-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enab
le-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt                                                 
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100                                                                      
  libavcodec     58. 42.104 / 58. 42.104                                                                      
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100                                                                      
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101                                                                      
  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101                                                                      
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100                                                                      
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100                                                                      
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100                                                                      
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920':                                                    
  Duration: N/A, start: 35609.500000, bitrate: N/A                                                            
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 
30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc                                                                        
Stream mapping:                                                                                               
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))                                                      
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help                                                                               
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2            
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit                                      
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http
://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 ps
y_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma
_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 con
strained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 k
eyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 
qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00                                                                              
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':                                                                                 
  Metadata:                                                                                                   
    encoder         : Lavf58.25.100                                                                           
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 10000k tbn
, 30 tbc                                                                                                      
    Metadata:                                                                                                 
      encoder         : Lavc58.42.104 libx264                                                                 
    Side data:                                                                                                
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1                                            
frame=   62 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.10 bitrate=   3.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.0495x  
frame=   77 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.60 bitrate=   0.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.237x   
frame=   92 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.09 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.363x   
frame=  107 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.59 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.453x   
frame=  168 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.63 bitrate= 577.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.654x   
frame=  183 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate= 507.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.683x   
frame=  198 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:04.63 bitrate= 452.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.706x   
frame=  213 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.13 bitrate= 817.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.727x   
frame=  228 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.63 bitrate= 744.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.744x   
frame=  243 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:06.13 bitrate= 683.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.759x   
frame=  259 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:06.66 bitrate= 629.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.777x   
frame=  274 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:07.16 bitrate= 585.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.789x   
frame=  289 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:07.66 bitrate= 547.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.799x   
frame=  301 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=     973kB time=00:00:09.93 bitrate= 802.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.975x  

video:969kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.445649%            
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] frame I:4     Avg QP:24.23  size: 13237                                          
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] frame P:77    Avg QP:24.67  size:  7807                                          
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] frame B:220   Avg QP:26.09  size:  1534                                          
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] consecutive B-frames:  2.3%  0.7%  0.0% 97.0%                                    
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] mb I  I16..4: 19.6% 70.5%  9.9%                                                  
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] mb P  I16..4:  3.6%  3.3%  0.3%  P16..4: 54.9% 11.7%  9.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:16
.8%                                                                                                           
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 28.2%  1.1%  0.2%  direct: 7.9%  skip:62
.2%  L0:51.0% L1:45.9% BI: 3.1%                                                                               
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] 8x8 transform intra:56.1% inter:69.3%                                            
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 35.2% 85.0% 30.8% inter: 9.3% 38.8% 1.5%                
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 34%  8% 27%                                                    
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 18% 28%  2%  3%  5%  3%  5%  3%               
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 40% 19%  8%  3%  6% 11%  4%  6%  3%               
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 16% 31%  5%                                                    
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.9% UV:1.3%                                                
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] ref P L0: 39.0%  6.6% 38.0% 16.3%  0.1%                                          
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] ref B L0: 61.8% 30.3%  7.9%                                                      
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] ref B L1: 84.4% 15.6%                                                            
[libx264 @ 000001ec0b750100] kb/s:790.62
```

Comment: Please include what `But it will fail on another` means. Please include the logs and whatever else could help identifying the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ive added more info here now - thank you for any help